# Summarising results of repeated hypothesis tests

Tags: r, for-loop, functional-programming

I am generating two sets of data from normal distributions using `rnorm(30, 10, 5)`. I am testing the hypothesis that the means are equal, using `t.test`, and repeating this process 1000 times to estimate the type 1 error rate.

My code is as follows:

```
for(i in 1:1000) {
  print(t.test(rnorm(30, 10, 5), rnorm(30, 10, 5),
               alternative="two.sided", var.equal=TRUE)$p.value < 0.05)
}
```

However, this returns countless `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

I can manually count the `TRUE`s, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not countless. There are 1000 of them ;)

Instead of printing the result to screen, you should keep track of it in a vector.

A simple change will get you what you want:

```
sig <- logical(length=1000)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  sig[i] <- t.test(rnorm(30, 10, 5), rnorm(30, 10, 5),
               alternative="two.sided", var.equal=TRUE)$p.value < 0.05
}
```

Now you can tabulate the results:

```
table(sig)
## sig
## FALSE  TRUE 
##   956    44
```

A simpler approach would be to use `replicate`:

```
table(replicate(1000, t.test(rnorm(30, 10, 5), rnorm(30, 10, 5), 
  alternative="two.sided", var.equal=TRUE)$p.value < 0.05))
```

Comment: First of all thanks for answering my question~ Later i figured it out using while                                                                                                  `i<-1000
k<-0
while(i>0){
            if(t.test(rnorm(30,10,5),rnorm(30,10,5),alternative="two.sided",var.equal=TRUE)$p.value<0.05)
             {k<-k+1}
          i<-i-1
                     }
> print(k)`                                                                                             Don't know if it's right but it seems to meet my needs. Just a beginner and thanks for your help again ><

Comment: @forRstudy - there are always many ways to approach a problem, and your suggestion is fine. Nice work figuring that out (though you could have stuck with your `for` loop, just adding the `k` stuff).